# $\forall \delta> 0 $, if $\mid a - b \mid \le \delta $ then $a = b$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> $\forall \delta> 0 $, if $\mid a - b \mid \le \delta $  then $a = b$

proof:

> Assume, by contradiction, WLOG   $a > b \to a - b > 0$   Let $d = a-
>  b$.
> Take $\delta = \frac{d}{2}$. Then we have   $\mid a - b \mid = a - b = d$
> is not $\le \delta$. Contradiction

My question is that:
when we prove $p \to q$ statement using contradiction, shouldn't we assume that $p$ is true and show the contradiction to $p$ when we assume $q$ is wrong?
The given proof doesn't assume $p$ is true in the beginning, does it?

If I set $\delta$ to $\frac{d}{2}$, does it satisfy that |a-b| is less or equal to $\delta$?

Comment: Be careful!  Your title statement (same as the first statement in your post) currently implies, say with $\delta=10^{10}$, that all numbers within $10^{10}$ of each other are equal.  "For all $\delta$ if $P(\delta)$ then $Q$" is not the same as "if $P(\delta)$ for all $\delta$ then $Q$".

Comment: @user10354138 I think I almost get it but not quite.. so the given proof is assuming $p$ is true? you're saying that "if $P(\delta)$ for all $\delta$ then $Q$" is the correct one, right?

Answer (score 2):

The proof assumes $p$ is true, where $p$ is the statement

$$\forall \delta>0: |a-b| \le \delta\tag{1}$$

and shows $q$ by contradiction where $q$ is $a=b$.

- Assume $a \neq b$.
- So $d=|a-b| >0$ by standard properties of the absolute value (in your text the defintiion interms of the ordered field structuree is used, but that amounts to the same thing).
- Apply our assumption $(1)$ to $\delta=\frac{d}{2}>0$, which is allowed as we have a universal quantor there. We get $d=|a-b| \le \frac{d}{2} < d$, a contradiction.

The final contradiction shows the first assumption $a \neq b$ was wrong, so $a=b$.

So from assuming $p$ we get $q$ (as $\lnot\lnot q$, so via contradiction).

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a proof by contradiction. It rather uses *Modus Tollens*: that is, given a statement $P$ which implies $Q$, then if we do not have $Q$, we can't have $P$, formally:

$(P \to Q) \iff (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$.

Translating to your concrete example, this reads:

> $(\forall \delta>0: \vert a -b \vert \leq \delta \implies a=b) \iff (a \neq b \implies \exists \delta >0 : \vert a - b \vert > \delta)$

The right hand side is exactly what the proof shows: assuming $a \neq b$ it shows the existence of $\delta = \frac{a-b}{2}$ such that $\vert a - b \vert > \delta$. Of course, you could turn it into a proof by contradiction as follows:

> Assume that $\forall \delta > 0: \vert a - b \vert \leq \delta$ and $a \neq b$. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $a > b$. Consider $\delta=\frac{a-b}{2}$. Then $\vert a - b \vert = a - b > \frac{a-b}{2} = \delta$, contradicting our assumption.

Answer (score 0):

For a statement $p$, contradiction is $\neg p\rightarrow \text{false}$.

Here $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\vee q$.

Thus
$\neg (p\rightarrow q)$ is equivalent to $p\wedge \neg q$ by DeMorgan.